# jQuery dynamically create elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that uses ColorBox. The `<a rel` link points to a folder that is automatically assigned to the date (i.e. 20140806). How would I make this more efficiently so I do not have to do it for every single date like the example below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel='20140804']").colorbox();
    $("a[rel='20140805']").colorbox();
    $("a[rel='20140806']").colorbox();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Add a class to the `<a>` tags, then just do `$('a.yourClass').colorbox();`.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to, you can use the selector "a[rel^=2014]". It will be possible only if your list is limited to the current year. You can be more precise, but you would be limited to the same month, same day etc..
If you want to keep it flexible, the first solution - use a class - seems to be a better one.

Comment: Rocket: I cannot do that because I cannot have them all grouped. Paul's suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prefix matching to catch any `rel` attribute starting with `201` (or `20`, to work for the rest of the century):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[rel^='201']").colorbox();
});
```

See [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do also :

```
$("a").each( function(){

   if ( $(this).attr(rel) == 'myValue' ){
       $(this).colorbox();
   }
});
```

For every hypertext in your document, you check whether if the 'rel' attribute matches with what you want

Answer (score 0):

As [Rocket Hazmat said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167584/jquery-dynamically-create-elements#comment39184313_25167584), you can add a CSS class to the links you want to apply colorbox to. At the same place, where you form your HTML links and `rel` attributes, you will have to add a CSS class, so your HTML will be like that:

```
<a href="/link/to/the/folder_1" class="colorbox-me">Folder 1</a>
[...]
<a href="/link/to/the/folder_N" class="colorbox-me">Folder N</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.colorbox-me").colorbox();
});
</script>
```

**It is also discouraged to use `rel` attribute for any purpose except describing relations of current document with the linked document.** `rel` attribute is usually used by search engines. Possible values of rel attribute may be found [here](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/RelExtensions).